# Grails + SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, grails, smartgwt

Trying to make Grails + smartgwt work together.

Setup:
Grails 2.2.1 (installed both, gwt + smartgwt plugin)
SmartGWT 3.1
GWT 2.5

After a couple of hours playing around with it, tomcat finally started. 
(created application and compiled the modules)

Project resides under:
zuhause:8080/gwt3/

Default module is foo.bar
Default index.gsp looks ok

```
<script>
var isomorphicDir = "${createLinkTo(dir: 'gwt/foo.bar.fooBar/sc/')}";
</script>

<!--                                           -->
<!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
<!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
<!-- be added before this line.                -->
<!--                                           -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="${createLinkTo(dir: 'gwt/foo.bar.foobar', file:   'foo.bar.foobar.nocache.js')}"></script>
```

The nocache.js is found
Inside the compiled "nocache.js" there is a reference to

```
zuhause:8080/gwt3/static/gwt/foo.bar.foobar/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The path reference to "static" is the one I have no idea where it is configured.

The module xml looks like:

```
<module>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>

<!-- Smart GWT -->
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools"/>


<!-- Specify the module entry point class.                   -->
<entry-point class="foo.bar.client.foobar"/>
```

I have scanned my complete project, but "static" has never been defined in one of the config files.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `static` is added by the [resources](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) plugin.